# PHP Regex help - match something="something\'s" with escaped single quote

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Trying to find a regular expression to handle this string using PHP preg_match_all:

```
include='Track Ass\'y'
```

The regex should be able to handle single OR double quotes, but not break on the escaped quote. Currently the regex in place looks like this:

```
/([^ ]*?)=["|'](.*?)(["|'])/
```

This breaks on the ' and only matches up to the single quote, and misses the final y'. Help?

Comment: i would explode on = and just remove the first and last charcter of the 2nd part

Comment: It's stopping before the `y` because of your lazy-match `?`. Remove the second question mark: `(.*)`

Comment: @Chin That solved it - can you put this as an answer and I will select it?

Comment: @the.s.brom There :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stopping before the `y` because of your lazy-match `?`.

Remove the second question mark:

```
(.*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
([^ ]*?)=["|'](.*?)(["|']\w['|"])
```

..works:

[image]

[try using a webtool](https://regex101.com/) to debug your regex.

Comment: was just going to link regex 101 to the OP.

Comment: OP already uses Regex 101 and Regexr, but it only helps so much when you are fuzzy on the bits and pieces of regular expressions.